# Prove or disprove that the points are aligned (Witch of Agnesi)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, projective-geometry

It's a little problem that I cannot disprove or prove .

We work with the following picture :

[image]

First we draw a circle and his tangent at point $D$ and $E$ .Secondly we draw the radius or the line $DE$.Thirdly we draw the line $EH$ and we get the points $I$ and $H$.Then we draw the parallel to the tangent of the circle wich goes at the point $I$ . And finally draw the perpendicular to the tangent of the circle wich goes to the point $H$ .We get the point $M$ wich is a point of the curve named Witch of Agnesi . Now we do the same things with the circle in red and in violet (always with the line $EH$).

> > Prove that $M$ ,$N$ , $R$ are aligned (line orange).

I don't find any counter-example so I was thinking to a proof . I have tried to prove that $\angle MRN=180^°$ and use the fact that we have many right triangles.Notably I think that  the line $MR$ goes through the intersection of the tangent of the red circle and the blue circle (same thing for the violet tangent and the red circle) .Finally I have tried to use Pappus's hexagon theorem without success. I think it's not hard but I need help on this question.

Thanks a lot for all your contributions.

Ps:The circle in red goes through the center of the blue circle (same things for the violet circle and the center of the red circle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prove this is with a use of analytic geometry.

Let $E=(0,0)$ and $D = (0,4a)$ and $$EH: \;\;y=kx\;\;$$ so $H=({4a\over k},4a)$. Notice that $DI\bot EH$ so the equation of $$DI:\;\; y= -{1\over k}x +4a$$

so $$I = \Big({4ak\over k^2+1}, {4ak^2\over k^2+1}\Big)$$ and thus

$$M = \Big({4a\over k}, {4ak^2\over k^2+1}\Big)$$ so we see that $M$ is on a line $$y= {k^3\over k^2+1}x$$

Similary we see that $N$ and $R$ are also on this line.

Notice that $F$ and $O$ can be choosen arbitrary on $DE$, need not to be the centers of circles.

Comment: it's good for me !